# Клик по кнопке input с известным её атрибутом name

Tags: delphi

Для начала я сделал с ней вот это:

```
inputEl := (doc.getElementsByName('subent').item(0,0) as IHTMLInputElement);
```

Тоже самое я делал с другими input строками, чтобы присвоить им какой-нибудь текст через "`inputEl.value := Текст`".

Насколько я понял, я присвоил inputEl тот самый input как объект. Но вот как кликнуть по кнопке input, если известно её атрибут name?

Answer (score 1):

получаешь элемент с искомым атрибутом - допустим ты назовешь его Element. Далее просто напиши Element.click;